# How can I create public-private key for a ERC20 wallet that using user's email address?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-20, public-key, hash-algorithm

I am working on a side project that provides a wallet (Think Coinbase, Binance, etc) like interface to users where they will sign in using username and password.

To be able to provide a clearer interface and ease of use, I would like to abstract them from all the complexities of public-private key.

How can I use their username/email or some unique id to generate a pair of keys to be used as wallet address and the corresponding private key to hold the ERC20 token?

I have explored the has functions within Solidity but now I am not even sure if this needs to be a smart contract?

Comment: I'd advice against generating private keys in a predictable way, for a private key to be secure it should be randomly generated.